# How to check context instance in MvvmCross android xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

### *How to write a Equivalent Code in MvvmCross for*

```
if (context instanceof Activity) {
  // handle activity case
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solution I used:***

```
if (context.GetType() == typeof(SplashView)) {
    // handle activity case         
}
```

- `context` is the `context` reference
- `SplashView` is the `Activity` name